# Benefits of Different SQLite Approaches when Developing Android App

Tags: java, android, sqlite, database-design

What's the best approach when it comes to processing data to be inserted to the SQLite database:

1. Write as much of the code with complex`TRIGGERS`inside the database itself.
2. Dynamically create`TEMPORARY TABLES`and similar solutions in`Java`.
3. Do the processing almost entirely in`Java`with primitive CRUD statements to manipulate the database?

I don't really have any real code to share, since I'm at conception, but what would the best way to for example enforce`FOREIGN KEYS`(i.e. delete rows that no longer has a connected value in the referenced table); with`TRIGGERS`or`Java`? Another example: would it be better to use the`Java`method`length()`instead of the following`TRIGGER`?

```
CREATE TABLE table ( column1 TEXT, column2 INTEGER );
CREATE TRIGGER tableTrigger INSERT ON table BEGIN INSERT INTO table VALUES ( NEW.column1 , LENGTH ( NEW.column1 ));
```

(Note: these are quite simple examples, and the`TRIGGERS`I'd end up with would be more complex, so I'm interested in a general approach or applicable rules of thumb.)

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the specific constraint you are trying to enforce.

For your first example, there is no need to write a trigger to enforce a foreign key relationship. SQLite will add this constraint for you when you define the column, by adding "ON DELETE CASCADE" (read more here: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

I would tend towards writing the logic in the application code itself, as that will be easier to debug than database triggers.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123074/sql-triggers-and-when-or-when-not-to-use-them